# Backup file folder in correct way

Tags: backup, tar

My situation is I only have execute permission from some folder:

Lets say, I would like to backup entire folder and exclude some folder and files with exclude.txt

Here is path I would like to backup:

```
/pdf/data/pdfnew/2014
```

And I only have permission to execute from this folder (main):

```
/pdf/data/pdfnew/2014/public/main
```

I put `exclude.txt` in same folder which I can execute the command (main)

I execute this command in (main folder):

```
tar -cjvf -X exclude.txt 2014.tar.bz2 /pdf/data/pdfnew/2014
```

The result is it still included folder that I dont want to backup.

Is there a correct way doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `user`/`home` directory on that server? You should, so you should just place `exclude.txt` in your `user`/`home`directory on that server & run it like this from that directory:

```
tar -cjvf -X ~/exclude.txt ~/2014.tar.bz2 /pdf/data/pdfnew/2014
```

The `~/` is a shorthand for your `user`/`home` directory so in this case it is explicitly stating, “Read `exclude.txt` from the `user`/`home` directory & write `~/2014.tar.bz2` to the `user`/`home` directory.

But you also ask this:

> Is there a correct way doing this?

There is never one canonical best way of doing something like this. It is all based on your final/end goal. Nothing more. Nothing less. That said, if I were you I would do it like this instead using the `-C` option:

```
tar -cjvf -X ~/exclude.txt ~/2014.tar.bz2 -C /pdf/data/pdfnew/ 2014
```

The uppercase `-C` option allows `tar` to internally [change the working directory](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/directory.html) to `/pdf/data/pdfnew/` so you can then create an archive of `2014` without having to have the whole directory tree retained in the backup. I find this is easier to work with because many times I want to backup the contents of a directory but have no use to retain the parent structure. That way the archive is more like a traditional ZIP archive which I find is easer to understand & work with.